# How to detect if a Zend Framework 2 application runs in console or HTTP context?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm writing a module to perform some tasks based on if the application is running in the console or HTTP context. Is there a way to detect this when the module is loaded?

For example, I try doing this with **Module.php** class.

```
namespace MyModule;

use ...

class Module
{
    public function init(ModuleManager $mm)
    {
        if (Console context) {
            // do something
        } else {
            // do something with HTTP
        }
    } 
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

Thats pretty easy. Just check if `Request` is an instance of `Zend\Http\Request` for Http and `Zend\Console\Request` for Console request. For example:

```
namespace Application;

use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\Http\Request as HttpRequest ;
use Zend\Console\Request as ConsoleRequest ;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        if ($e->getRequest() instanceof HttpRequest) {
            // do something important for Http
        } elseif($e->getRequest() instanceof ConsoleRequest ) {
            // do something important for Console
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: I would definitely do it this way.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use `php_sapi_name()`

> Although not exhaustive, the possible return values include aolserver, apache, 
>    apache2filter, apache2handler, caudium, cgi (until PHP 5.3), cgi-fcgi, cli, continuity, 
>    embed, isapi, litespeed, milter, nsapi, phttpd, pi3web, roxen, thttpd, tux, and webjames.

So I would do:

```
if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli') { 
  //console
} else {
  //not console
}
```